# HK2 Proxy vs javax.inject.Provider

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

I have two singleton services bound to the dependency injector (via Jersey):

```
ResourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Foo.class)
            .to(Foo.class)
            .in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Bar.class)
            .to(Bar.class)
            .in(Singleton.class);
    }
});
```

`Foo` uses `Bar`, so I can simply do the following:

```
public class Foo {
    @javax.inject.Inject private Bar bar;
}
```

If `Foo` only uses `Bar` rarely, then I can defer its construction:

```
public class Foo {
    @javax.inject.Inject private javax.inject.Provider<Bar> bar;
}
```

I have also read that using `Provider` is recommended in general as it avoids this eager evaluation and circular dependencies (though I try to avoid those anyway).

But what about making it a proxy?:

```
ResourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Foo.class)
            .to(Foo.class)
            .in(Singleton.class)
            .proxy(true)
            .proxyForSameScope(true);
        bind(Bar.class)
            .to(Bar.class)
            .in(Singleton.class)
            .proxy(true)
            .proxyForSameScope(true);
    }
});
```

I am new to injection so not sure on the history.  Are they effectively the same concept for the two different frameworks?

A proxy makes the code look nicer and pushes the concern to the creator of the service instead of the user of it (which may or may not be desirable).  Is there any disadvantage to this versus `Provider`?

Note the only thing being considered here is singleton services.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice. like for some [Jersey services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53019187/2587435), they didn't make it proxiable, so you need to use the `Provider`. In general though, if possible, I imagine proxy is preferred, just because it is less verbose. But some instances the proxy is not possible. As far as (dis)advantages, besides being less verbose, I can't really think of any.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely an opinion, but I would prefer the proxy myself, for most of the reasons you mentioned.  It is better in general to proxy interfaces because then the JDK proxies are used but as long as your Bar class follows the proxy rules you should still be ok.