# jax-rs share information between ContainerRequestFilter and ReaderInterceptor

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jax-rs, and I'm doing some logic in the `Filters`, and then I would like to  share information between `ContainerRequestFilter`(Filter) and `ReaderInterceptor`(Interceptor).

I can see that between Filters and Interceptors is possible through the `set/getProperties` but between Filter and Interceptors is not possible.

Any idea if there's any other mechanism?.

Regards.

Comment: You can use DI and a service.

Comment: Could you elaborate how create this dependency between them can help me?.

Comment: I made it using DI as you mention. Great idea!! Thanks!

Comment: It is the filter is called before the reader so it fit perfectly with DI

Answer (score 1):

You can use a request scoped service that you inject into both the filter and the interceptor. For instance

```
public interface RequestScopedService {
    void setSomething(Object something);
    Object getSomething();
}

public class RequestScopedServiceImpl implements RequestScopedService {
    @Override
    public void setSomething(Object something) {}

    @Override
    public Object getSomething() {}
}
```

It's best practice to use interfaces, that's why I did that here. To configure it, you register an `AbstractBinder` with your `ResourceConfig` <sup>1</sup>.

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(RequestScopedServiceImpl.class)
                        .to(RequestScopedService.class)
                        .proxy(true)
                        .proxyForSameScope(false)
                        .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can inject it into both the filter and the interceptor.

```
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final RequestScopedService service;

    @Inject
    public MyFilter(RequestScopedService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {
    private final RequestScopedService service;

    @Inject
    public MyInterceptor(RequestScopedService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

We use the `proxy()` method to configure it because the service is a request scoped service (meaning a new one is created for each request) and the filter and writer interceptor are singletons. So we need it to be a proxy that forwards calls to the real service under the hood <sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub>1. If you are not using a `ResourceConfig` for your configuration (maybe you are using web.xml), see both [my answer in "Dependency Injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275727/2587435) and [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435).</sub>

<sub>2. You can learn some more about this in [this article](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/12/16/request-scope-into-singleton-scope.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

So any easier way than [using a separate service for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52994970/2587435) is to simply inject the `ContainerRequestContext` into the `ReaderInterceptor`. We need to inject it as a [`javax.inject.Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) so that we can lazy retrieve it. If we don't do this, we will run into scoping issues, as the interceptor is inherently a singleton and the request context is request scoped (meaning a new one is created for each request).

```
public static class MyInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {
    private final javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequestContext> requestProvider;

    @Inject
    public MyInterceptor(javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequestContext> requestProvider) {
        this.requestProvider = requestProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext readerInterceptorContext) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        ContainerRequestContext request = requestProvider.get();
        String prop = (String) request.getProperty("SomeProp");
    }
}
```

With the `javax.inject.Provider`, we get the actual service by calling `get()`. Because we are using `Provider`, the service will be retrieved from a request scoped context, meaning that the instance will be tied to the request.

---

<sub>1. See [Request Scoped Injection into a Singleton with Jersey](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/12/16/request-scope-into-singleton-scope.html) for more information.</sub>

Comment: So is not possible a Rc where a second request override the container while I’m processing already in the reader interceptor?

Comment: No, it will be a proxy, that makes calls to the actual one under the hood. The actual one will be held in a threadlocal under the hood (hence the term 'threadlocal proxy'). You can google it if you never heard this term. [Here's some more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45250106/2587435)

Comment: I will try it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry and what about if the container must be instanciated by Spring? I guess it would be a problem?

Comment: What container?

Comment: The containerrequestinterceotor is configure in Spring xml to be instanciated or not. And I don’t know if that will make the scope of the instance Singleton instead of request scope proxy as you mention.

Comment: Try it. If it doesn't work, try to use `@Context` instead of `@Inject`. For constructor injection, the `@Context` annotation goes before the parameter, not on the constructor.

Comment: To prove that works in every new request in the reader interceptor, The constructor with the inject it should always be called?

Comment: To prove that it works is if you get no exceptions. Don't worry about that part. It's handled by the `Provider`. Read up on proxies. All the links I gave you.

Comment: My concern to prove that there’s no Race conditions  thanks!

Comment: I was mistaken. The request context will not be a proxy. It will be the actual instance. This is made possible by a request scoped context. When we lazily retrieve it, it will be obtained from this context, which is tied to each request. There will be no possible race conditions because each request gets its own instance of the context. In my previous answer, it _would_ be a proxy because we aren't using `Provider`.